# Variables not being correctly rendered into HTML with Meteor (probably a Data Context issue)

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to create a link in my web page to each of the users' posts. I have succeeded in creating the new page (message.html) for each post (the "Hello World" for this web page is displayed correctly, see below). However and in contrast to my main page, the variables I want to render into the HTML fail to be displayed. Thanks in advance!

Notes: 
Routing was done with Flow Router.

Here are the relevant snippets of code:

**Message.js** (or controller for the html)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Boosts } from '../api/boosts.js';

import './boost.js';
import './message.html';

Template.ApplicationLayout2.onCreated(function messagesOnCreated() {
  Meteor.subscribe('messages');
});

Template.boostPage.helpers({
messages() {
  return Boosts.findOne(this._id());
  },
});
```

**Message.html** (or html to be displayed when a new page is opened)

Note: the *Hello World* in this html is placed as an example of what can be effectively displayed in the browser.

```
<template name="ApplicationLayout2">
Hello World
    {{> boostPage}}
</template>

<template name="boostPage">
    {{#with messages}}
    <h2>Boost: {{text}}</h2>
    <q class="message">{{message}}</q>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

**Boosts.js (relevant part)** (Meteor.publish('boosts', function boostsPublication()...) is not relevant for this problem but I included it to keep the code's original format)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Match } from 'meteor/check';

export const Boosts = new Mongo.Collection('boosts'); 

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('boosts', function boostsPublication() {
    return Boosts.find({
      $or: [
        { private: { $ne: true } },
        { owner: this.userId },
      ],
    });
  });
  Meteor.publish('messages', function messagesPublication() {
    return Boosts.find({
        {_id: this._id},
    });
  });
}
```

**Routes.js**

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name:'home',
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('ApplicationLayout');
  }
});


FlowRouter.route('/boosts/:_id', {
  name:'messages',
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("ApplicationLayout2", {_id: this._id});
  }
});
```

**EDIT #1**  I included the corrections suggested by zim.

**Message.js** (or controller for the html)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Boosts } from '../api/boosts.js';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './boost.js';
import './message.html';

Template.Message.onCreated(function() {
    // get the message id from the route parameter
    let messageId = FlowRouter.getParam('messageid');

    // save it to a reactive var so the helper can use it
    this.messageId = new ReactiveVar(messageId);

    // subscribe to 1 message using that message id
    this.subscribe('message', messageId);
});

Template.Message.helpers({
    // get data for 1 message
    message() {
        let messageId = Template.instance().messageId.get();
        return Boosts.find({_id: messageId});
    }
});
```

**Message.html** (or html to be displayed when a new page is opened)

Note: the *Hello World* and the **Boost:** header together with *object Object* surrounded between quotes are displayed in the browser.

```
<template name="Message">
Hello World
    {{#with message}}
    <h2>Boost: {{text}}</h2>
    <q class="message">{{message}}</q>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

**Boosts.js (relevant part)** (Meteor.publish('boosts', function boostsPublication()...) is not relevant for this problem but I included it to keep the code's original format)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Match } from 'meteor/check';

export const Boosts = new Mongo.Collection('boosts');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  // Only publish boosts that are public or belong to the current user
  Meteor.publish('boosts', function boostsPublication() {
    return Boosts.find({
      $or: [
        { private: { $ne: true } },
        { owner: this.userId },
      ],
    });
  });
    // Publish only the message corresponding to the boost in question
    Meteor.publish('message', function(messageId) {
    return Boosts.find({_id: messageId});
  });
}
```

**Routes.js**

```
  FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name:'home',
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('ApplicationLayout');
  }
});


FlowRouter.route('/boosts/:messageid', {
  name:'messages',
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("Message", {messageid: this._id});
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on browser console?

Comment: None at all, that is what puzzles me. I only have the classic "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap:" which I have learned to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this publish:

```
  Meteor.publish('messages', function messagesPublication() {
    return Boosts.find({
        {_id: this._id},
    });
  });
```

... what are you expecting "this._id" to represent? did you log it to the console? i suspect it's undefined.

update:

let's say you have a route like this: /message/:messageid

you can have a single message template like this:

Message.html:

```
<template name="Message">
    {{#with message}}
      {{content}}    <!-- or some field within message -->
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Message.js:

```
Template.Message.onCreated(function() {
    // get the message id from the route parameter
    let messageId = FlowRouter.getParam('messageid');

    // save it to a reactive var so the helper can use it
    this.messageId = new ReactiveVar(messageId);

    // subscribe to 1 message using that message id
    this.subscribe('message', messageId);
});

Template.Message.helpers({
    // get data for 1 message
    message() {
        let messageId = Template.instance().messageId.get();
        return Boosts.find({_id: messageId});
    }
});
```

that's a simple template for getting the data for a single message, and displaying it. now you need to publish that single message:

server.js:

```
  Meteor.publish('message', function(messageId) {
    return Boosts.find({_id: messageId});
  });
```

that's one way of doing it. note the flow: the router defines the id of the message, the template subscribes to it, that tells the server to publish it, and then the helper does a find on that published data.

you could also create a template that loops through the messages. here, we're subscribing to all the message data, and publishing it all. (note how i'm naming things in singular and plural to help convey the concept)

Messages.html:

```
<template name="Messages">
    {{#each message in messages}}
      {{message.content}}    <!-- or some field within message -->
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Messages.js:

```
Template.Messages.onCreated(function() {
    // subscribe to all the messages
    this.subscribe('messages');
});

Template.Messages.helpers({
    // get data for all the messages
    messages() {
        return Boosts.find();
    }
});
```

this publishes all the data:

server.js:

```
  Meteor.publish('messages', function() {
    return Boosts.find();
  });
```

in this example, we're not pulling any info from the route, but looping through all the messages.

does that help?

Comment: No I did not log it to the console. I expect it to return the id of the clicked boost (post); I want the returned _id to be dependent on the boost clicked by the user so that message.html can display a message related to the boost in question.

Comment: @Lesscomfortable, the publish isn't going to know what is happening on the client unless you either 1) publish everything and do the find() on the client for the clicked item, or 2) pass to the publish the id of what was clicked, let it publish, and do the find() after the data arrives.

Comment: in (1) do you mean doing the find() in the subscribe? (the subscribe for messages is in messages.js which is imported into client.js in the client folder). If so how could I edit the data before I subscribe it? I am asking this because until now I have always subscribed directly whatever I published so I am not too comfortable with editing in the subscribe.

Comment: I'm sorry if any of this sound foolish, I am still struggling to understand Meteor correctly.

Comment: @Lesscomfortable, check my answer, i added some example code for handling single and multiple messages. should put you on the right path.

Comment: That's great zim, makes perfect sense and thank you for the kind explanation. However, I tried it and checked it a few times and it does not seem to work. At least now I can see the **Boost** header I included which is within the {{with messages}} {{/with}}. I guess this means it is recognizing the _with_ statement but it is not finding any data to display. On the other hand, this would be strange because I have double-checked that the _id exists and there is a message field (the one I mean to display) for that _id.

Comment: you can install meteor toys (https://atmospherejs.com/meteortoys/allthings) and use it to see what data has been published to your client. if it's correct, then the error is in how you're trying to find/display it. if it's not, then the error is in the publish. if you can update your question w/ the current code, that would help.

Comment: it's great to learn new tools as you debug! The data is not available in meteor toys which suggests it has not been published to the client. Couldn't this mean that there may be an error in the subscribe? I updated the code to show the changes you suggested.

Comment: i would check to make sure you're getting the right messageid from your route; i don't think you need to pass it in from your route (it should just be available). Also, for the {{#with}}, i checked our codebase and we always do a findOne() in the helper, not a find(). So once the data is getting published, you'll probably have to fix that as well.

Comment: I got it! I changed what you said and, more importantly (and foolishly), I was using the users _id instead of  the posts _id. After changing this, the {{text}} appeared but not the {{message}}. Instead, in the place of message I got an "object Object". This was due to the fact that meteor was confounding the message string from Boosts.findOne and the 'message' object sent by the helper. I changed the name of the 'message' object to 'messages' and it now works! Thanks so much zim and sorry for my carelessness!